# Why did my wallpaper stop working?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, motorola-droid-razr, live-wallpaper

I just upgraded to Android 4.1 Jellybean (OTA carrier update to my Verizon Droid RAZR MAXX), and my Multipicture Live Wallpaper app is not loading any pictures. Previously, each screen would load pictures from a folder on my SD card. Now, it says "Picture is unavailable. Need to setup or reload". I checked, and the path is still the same in the settings, and the pictures are at those locations. Why did this stop working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error. Instead of selecting pictures from a folder, use the album, and the picture folder will be listed as an album. Deselect all the other albums, and pictures should show up.